# Найти ближайшее квадратное число (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

Не принимает решение задачи на [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5a805d8cafa10f8b930005ba/train/javascript)

```js
function nearestSq(n) {
  if (Math.sqrt(n) % 1 === 0) {
    return n
  } else {
    for (let i = 1; Math.sqrt(n) % 1 !== 0; i++) {
      n++;
    }
    return n
  }
}

nearestSq(122);
```

В консоли браузера все работает. Я или неправильно понял условие задачи, или что не так? Спасибо.

Comment: там даже есть кнопка "Test", которая тебе скажет в каком тесте ошибка. Правильно работает у него... Ты вообще результаты своего кода проверял?

Comment: Попробуйте  *n = 2*. Ваш код выдаст *4*. Правильный ответ *1*.

Comment: простите, не вникая сильно в смысла написанного, зачем у вас цикл? там разве не надо вычислить квадратный корень, округлить вниз, вверх, возвести оба числа в квадрат и посмотреть что ближе к искомому?

Comment: "Ожидалось что 4 равно 1". Что я должен из этого понять? При том, что в условии сказано, выводить n если число является полным квадратом(т.е. корень без остатка извлекается)

Comment: 4 - то, что вернул твой код. 1 - то, что он должен был вернуть.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function nearestSq(n){
    return Math.pow(Math.round(Math.sqrt(n)), 2);
}
```

Ответ

Comment: Можно доказать что это правильный код. Супер!

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy что-то у меня мозги совсем заржавели.

Comment: На 2.3 выдаёт неправильный ответ. Но для целых работает.